# Is there a way to run my Windows VB.NET program through Mono?

Tags: mono

I'm still a newbie, but I wrote a program in Visual Studio Express 2012 on Windows with references to an API through a .dll and .NET framework 4.0. If I try it on Ubuntu, I get messages like "Could Not Load File Or Assembly". Is there a way to run this on Ubuntu? If so, how do I get it to work?

Comment: What kind of dll? Does your program use a Windows native dll, or is the dll itself an assembly? That is, is the dll a "normal" windows library or is it a .NET library like your program?

Comment: It's a .NET library.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. You can't simply compile your .net code under Windows and then expect it to run under linux like this:
mono myprog.exe

You have to compile it under Linux first - so first download the vb compiler
apt-get install mono-vbnc

then copy your source code over and compile like this
vbnc myprog.vb

then run like this:
mono myprog.exe

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Some VB.net applications will run on ubuntu using mono. In general support for them is not as good as for c#.

You can run your application from the commandline as follows:

```
mono YourAssembly.exe
```

Comment: trampster Unfortunately, that didn't work. I thought that maybe I was doing it wrong, but it looks like that just wasn't possible. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that simply installing mono on your ubuntu as follows

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

After installation of mono

```
mono test.exe
```

If you want to browse more about mono visit: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page